# Show that $p!$ and $(p - 1)! - 1$ are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

> If $p$ is prime number, with $p>3$
>
> Show that $p!$ and $(p - 1)! - 1$ are relatively prime.
>
> I tried
>
> $\text{gcd}\;(p!,(p-1)!-1)=d\Longrightarrow d\mid p!$ e $d\mid(p-1)!-1$ having to $p!=p\cdot(p-1)!$ and $d\mid p!$ then, $$d\mid p\cdot(p-1)!$$
>
> Soon $d\mid p$ or $d\nmid p$.
>
> (I)
>
> If $d\mid p\Longrightarrow d=1$ or $d=p$
>
> We have $d\mid (p-1)!-1$ and Wilson's Theorem we have $$p\mid (p-1)!+1$$and $(p-1)!-1=(p-1)!+1-2$ We know by Theorem Wilson $p\mid (p-1)!+1$, then $$p\nmid (p-1)!+1-2$$ because $p>3$, then $p\neq d$, soon $d=1$.
>
> (II)
>
> If $d\nmid p\Longrightarrow d\mid (p-1)!$
>
> As $d\mid (p-1)!$ and $d\mid (p-1)!-1$, then $d\mid 1\Longrightarrow d=1$.
>
> $\Box$

***You demonstration is complete, or is something missing? Something wrong? Another way?***

Comment: Note that $d\nmid p$ is not compatible with $d=1$...

Comment: Excluding like you did $d=p$, simply note that a divisor $d$ of $(p-1)!$ gets a remainder equal to -1 once trying to divide $(p-1)!-1$...

Comment: It's hard for me to understand because I do not speak english, but I'm trying... :D

Answer (score 2):

Since $(p-1)!-1$ is relatively prime to every integer smaller than $p,$ the only way the two quantities could fail to be relatively prime is if $p|(p-1)!-1.$  But $p|(p-1)!+1,$ and $p>2,$ so that's impossible.

Comment: The statement is correct or not?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: the title statement is correct, this is another way to prove that it is true.

Comment: Why does $p|(p-1)!+1$ ?

Comment: Wilson's theorem

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is nearly complete.  For part (II), I would suggest that instead of concluding that $d=1$, conclude that the assumption for this part (that $d\nmid p$) contradicts the result that $d\mid 1$, therefore that this case leads to a contradiction and cannot occur.

Then conclude that the result from part (I) is the only logical result, which is that

$$\text{gcd}(p!,(p-1)!-1)=1$$